# Calling upon a global variable

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

This is intended to be a one question quiz. When you choose your answer and hit "submit" it *should* output your answer and your score out of 1.

The problem is it isn't reading "var response" correctly - it comes out undefined.

I was hoping a second set of eyes can help me address the problem

All help is appreciated :)

```
<p id="question">
<button type="button" class="start" onclick="test();">Start</button>
</p>

<p id="here"></p>

<script>

    function test() {
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML =
          "<p>What color is the sky? <select id='list' onchange='score();'><option value='Not Sure' selected>Not Sure</option><option value='Blue'>Blue</option><option value='Red'>Red</option></select></p><button type='button' onclick='submit();'>submit</button>";
    }

    var total = 0;
    var response = document.getElementById('list').value;
    function score() {
        var response = document.getElementById('list').value;
        if (response === "Blue") {
            total++;
        }
    }

    function submit() {
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML =
          "Your Answer:" + response + "<br />" + total + "/1";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The issue is, that you read the _value_ during loading of the page into var _response_. And Later you use this (probably empty) _response_. But like nnnnnn suggests, you need to do this whenever (e.g. in submit function) you need the current value of the field.

Comment: Your response isn't setting when you are submitting. in submit function do `response = doc........lue`. and see what happens, also you don't need to do `var response` twice

Answer (score 2):

You currently have two `response` variables, the first one being global and assigned to a value from a field that doesn't exist yet, and the second being local within the `score()` function.

You need to *declare* the variable outside the functions, but *set* its value inside `score()`:

```js
function test() {
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML =
      "<p>What color is the sky? <select id='list' onchange='score();'><option value='Not Sure' selected>Not Sure</option><option value='Blue'>Blue</option><option value='Red'>Red</option></select></p><button type='button' onclick='submit();'>submit</button>";
}

var total = 0;
var response = "Not sure";
function score() {
    // 'var' removed from following line:
    response = document.getElementById('list').value;
    if (response === "Blue") {
        total++;
    }
}

function submit() {
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML =
      "Your Answer:" + response + "<br />" + total + "/1";
}
```

```html
<p id="question">
<button type="button" class="start" onclick="test();">Start</button>
</p>

<p id="here"></p>
```

(Also, not what you're asking, but it doesn't make sense to call `score()` from the select element's `onchange`, because if the user changes their mind back and forth from Blue to Red several times then the `total` variable gets incremented several times and they can get a score like `3/1`. It would be better to do all the calculations in response to the submit button click.)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "var" inside the below method which is redefining the global variable inside the function scope.

```
function score() {
        response = document.getElementById('list').value;
        if (response === "Blue") {
            total++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with this line

```
var response = document.getElementById('list').value;
```

When this line is parsed there is not element with id `list` present in dom. Hence you are seeing `undefined`.

You can try by assigning this variable inside the `test` function

```
function test() {
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML =
    "<p>What color is the sky? <select id='list' onchange='score();'><option value='Not Sure' selected>Not Sure</option><option value='Blue'>Blue</option><option value='Red'>Red</option></select></p><button type='button' onclick='submit();'>submit</button>";
  response = document.getElementById('list').value;

}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4v6e91/1/)

Comment: This doesn't work - note in your demo that upon clicking submit it doesn't display the current selection.

Comment: @nnnnnn the objective was to resolve the problem of  'undefined'. Hence I dont think he expected to resolve the rest of code